# What is difference between max_concurrent_queries_for_all_user and max_concurrent_queries in clickhouse setting？

Tags: clickhouse

I am beginner for Clickhouse. I referred to the Clickhouse documentation, but I am confused.

In ClickHouse, how do these `max_concurrent_queries_for_all_user` and `max_concurrent_queries` settings affect the number of concurrent queries?

Answer (score 0):

But it's explained in the documentation?

*Example: max_concurrent_queries_for_all_users can be set to 99 for all users and database administrator can set it to 100 for itself to run queries for investigation even when the server is overloaded.*